# Acquia Dev Desktop and Drush broken with syntax is incorrect

Tags: drush, acquia-dev-desktop

I did a clean install of Acquia Dev Desktop (Build Nov 13th, 2017) under Windows 10. I can clone my site (Drupal 8) and then click to open my local Drush console. It opens a DOS prompt into the docroot directory. When I execute any drush commands I get "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Here is a sample:

> C:\DevDesktop\website-dev\docroot>drush -d -d  version
>
> Loading drushrc "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\drushrc.php" into "drush" scope.   [bootstrap]
>
> [0.78 sec, 2.48 MB]
>   Cache HIT cid: 8.1.15-commandfiles-0-61c5476a3a04a40d4bdadfd521f0641f [0.84 sec, 2.52 MB]                          [debug]
>
> Begin redispatch via drush_invoke_process(). [1.16 sec, 6.43 MB]                                                  [notice]
>
> Backend invoke: "C:\DevDesktop\website-dev\docroot\vendor\bin\drush.launcher"                            [command]
>   --root="C:\DevDesktop\website-dev\docroot" --debug --verbose  version 2>&1 [1.21 sec, 6.45 MB]
>
> Calling proc_open("C:\DevDesktop\website-dev\docroot\vendor\bin\drush.launcher"  --root="C:\DevDesktop\website-dev\docroot" --debug --verbose  version 2>&1);
>
> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   End redispatch via drush_invoke_process(). [1.24 sec, 6.44 MB]                                                    [notice]

Comment: I would update DevDesktop to the latest version and try again first. There are couple drush updates.

Comment: The known issues (#1) says not to for windows https://docs.acquia.com/dev-desktop/known-issues/. I tried anyway, didn't work and I rolled back to the Nov 2017 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acquia Dev Desktop (ADD) comes with Drush 8 included. When you call `drush` the version coming with ADD is started (as you can see from the "Loading drushrc" debug). That version of Drush is then detecting your site local version of Drush - the one located in the vendor directory of your Drupal installation. (Just look at the path from the "Backend invoke" debug.)

The problem is that `drush.launcher` doesn't work on Windows.

There are two options that probably solves the problem:

1. Update your site local Drush to Drush 9 with Composer. This my recommended solution. (Drush 9 doesn't have `drush.launcher`)
2. If you don't want to use Drush 9, just delete the site local Drush with Composer.

PS! This problem is not related to the known Windows issue with ADD.

Comment: #1 - upgrading to Drush 9 doesn't resolve the issue. 
The same issue persists. As suggested on github drush issue page "cd  into vendor/bin" in order to invoke composer drush. Otherwise remove composer Drush package and use Acquia DD Drush.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue on windows 10 with Acquia Dev Desktop and configured existing Drupal 8 project from a client.

Following three things what I did worked for me.

I simply:

1. Removed directory **vendor/drush**
2. Removed directory **vendor/bin**
3. Removed line `"drush/drush": "^8.1"` from **composer.json** which is located on docroot directory.

Now, default drush is working for me as you can see the default drush version at `C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools\composer.json`.

Hopefully, this will help someone else.

Comment: Helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case installing drush through composer is what caused the error for me.  I also had issues removing it with composer, so in order to get it working I manually removed the following:

```
/vendor/drush/
/vendor/bin/drush
```

After that it worked fine for me.